# Java - Reading from file issues

Tags: java, filereader

Hello so I am trying to write code where I read data from a file, but I am at a loss. I have done this once before but the file that I read from looked like:

> Al      90      80      70
>
> Becky   80      85      90
>
> Chuck   70      90      80
>
> Deb     90      95      90
>
> Ed      90      85      90

So I was able to made a program to read the Names as string then the numbers and perform some caclulations since the .txt file was printed out the way it is.
So now my professor wants us to do it again but this time the file is a .op file and it looks like this [http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/~bsetzer/2302sp15/extra/data/747812-63813-2013.op](http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/%7Ebsetzer/2302sp15/extra/data/747812-63813-2013.op)
I am not sure if I am asking this right but how do I write code where it reads from each one of those columns. I have tried a few things but the fact that there are words on top screws me up. Just to test, I had it read everything as a string and print it and it worked. So can any of you explain a good way to make a program read that data? EDIT: yay for downvotes. just trying to ask for help and i get all the downvotes. so glad i came here.

Comment: whats wrong with reading the entire data and working on each line at a time?

Comment: don't know how to do that.

Comment: Are you doing this in JavaScript or Java? They are not the same. Please remove one of the tags.

Comment: Also, please do not rely on external sites for data. Include a couple of rows of the data in your question, so that if linked site dissapears future visitors will still be able to understand your question.

Comment: yeah that is too big to copy and paste

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure if I am asking this right but how do I write code where
>   it reads from each one of those columns.

To read from each column, read each line as a string, then you can now split the line into different columns. From there you would be able to manipulate the data as you wish.

**Example**

> String val="Al 90 80 70"
>
> val.split`("\\s+");`

**Explanation**

`("\\s+")`: This is a regex pattern that splits the string using one or more space

Comment: that sound way to advanced for me

Comment: also that al 90 80 70 isn't the issue it is what is in the link that i don't know how to read into a file.

Comment: Do you want me to write a program, illustrating an example?

Comment: i love examples. i would greatly appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

```
  try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.contains("STN---"))
                continue;
            String [] cols = line.split(" ");
            // process the columns
        }
    }
```

you should add a flag to avoid checking for the substring on each line.

Comment: tried that but i don't think it likes that the file is a .op

Comment: file extension doesn't matter.

Comment: so if the file is 636870-99999-2013.op then the first line would be try '(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(636870-99999-2013.op ))) { ' or would it be different? I have never used FileReader

Comment: ok got this to work. Now how do i read the data now that I have processed the columns?